# Proper way to simplify this triple integral into a workable form

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

For a homework problem, I need to integrate $
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1/(v^3+a^3)&\text{if}\, v\leq v_0\\
 0& \text{else}\\   
\end{cases}
$ where a is a constant and $v = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$

I initially thought to try $\iiint 1/([v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2]^{3/2}+a^2) dv_xdv_ydv_z
$
and worry about bounds after integrating, but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

I then thought maybe I could do something along the lines of $\int_{0}^{v_0} 1/(v^3+a^3)dv$ , but I feel like I'm not allowed to do this. It also gives a very complicated result, that I believe to be beyond the scope of the problem.

How should I approach this integral?

Comment: You need to transform this integral to spherical coordinates.

Comment: That is an excellent point. Thanks a bunch!